# GestureDetector and slide when longpress on

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

[image]

I want to slide microphone icon which is wrapping with container, I added this container into GestureDetector Widget when longpress is on , container can slide to delete record it means return isRecording = false, but all issues about UI, below the code what I trying

```dart
 GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: () async {
      await pressStart();
    },
    onLongPressUp: () async {
      await pressUp();

      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        setState(() {
          _onFileUploadButtonPressed();
          _onRecordAgainButtonPressed();
        });
      });
    },
    child: _isRecording != true
        ? Container(
            height: 55,
            width: 53,
            child: Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.mic,
                size: 30,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 10),
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      color: Colors.grey)
                ],
                color: Colors.black,
                shape: BoxShape.circle),
          )
        : Container(
            height: 90,
            width: 90,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 10),
                          blurRadius: 100,
                          color: Colors.grey)
                    ],
                    color: Colors.red[300],
                    shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.pause_circle_filled,
                  size: 60,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      offset: Offset(0, 10),
                      blurRadius: 10,
                      color: Colors.grey)
                ],
                color: Colors.red,
                shape: BoxShape.circle),
          )),
```

**At the below , there are functions that ı use for recording voice and upload to firestore and firebase storage.**

```
Future<void> pressStart() async {
//anlasildi
_isRecorded = false;
_isRecording = true;
 before = DateTime.now();
 await _startRecording();
 }

  Future<void> pressUp() async {
//anlasildi
 _audioRecorder!.stop().then((value) => after = DateTime.now());
  setState(() {
  _isRecording = false;
  _isRecorded = true;
  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Yükleniyor..');
  });
  }

 Future<void> _startRecording() async {
//anlasildi
    final bool? hasRecordingPermission =
    await FlutterAudioRecorder2.hasPermissions;
     if (hasRecordingPermission!) {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String filepath = directory.path +
      '/' +
      DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
      '.aac';
  _audioRecorder =
      FlutterAudioRecorder2(filepath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC);
  await _audioRecorder!.initialized;
  _audioRecorder!.start();
  _filePath = filepath;
  setState(() {});
  } else {
  SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('Please enable recording permission'),
  );
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}

 

     Future<void> _onFileUploadButtonPressed() async {
setState(() {
  _isUploading = true;
});
UploadTask reference = firebaseStorage
    .ref('upload-voice-firebase')
    .child(_filePath!
        .substring(_filePath!.lastIndexOf('/'), _filePath!.length))
    .putFile(File(_filePath!));
try {
  TaskSnapshot snapshot = await reference;
  voiceUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  Duration durations = after!.difference(before!);
  String minuteString =
      '${(durations.inSeconds / 60).floor() < 10 ? 0 : ''}${(durations.inSeconds / 60).floor()}';
  String secondString =
      '${durations.inSeconds % 60 < 10 ? 0 : ''}${durations.inSeconds % 60}';
  String lasttime = '$minuteString:$secondString';
  setState(() {
    onSendMessage(voiceUrl, 2, lasttime);
  });
} catch (error) {
  print('Error occured while uplaoding to Firebase ${error.toString()}');
  SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('Error occured while uplaoding'),
  );
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
} finally {
  setState(() {
    _isUploading = false;
  });
}
```

}

Comment: do you mean onlongPress `_isRecording` will change the value ? in that case i dont see any `setState()` for `_isRecording `

Comment: the pressStart() method is returning this value which is _isRecording in onLongPress() , ı want to check with this value if it is true then it can be slide to left if users want to do it or when users onLongPressUp it will upload audio to firebase with _onFileUploadButtonPressed() method.

Comment: can you share those methods , so that i can check what are you doing there.

Comment: of course , ı have edit this post you can check the methods which is needed.